# Javascript Radiobutton Group Validation

Tags: javascript, html, validation, radio-button, radio-group

I would like your help to develop a javascript function to validate if one of the following radiobutton group (IDType) is selected and which value is checked and view error message in (ValidationError) division in case no radio button selected ??

```
<td>
<div>
<span>
<input type="radio" name="IDType" id="IDType" value="IDtype1"/>
ID Type 1
<input type="radio" name="IDType" id="IDType" value="IDtype2"/>
ID Type 2
</span>
<div id="ValidationError" name="ValidationError">
&nbsp;
</div>
</div>
</td>
```

Thanks for your help.....

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? We are not in the habit of writing your code for you, but will be happy to help with any problems.

Comment: Both of your `input[type=radio]` elements have the same `id`. `id` values (unlike `name` values) **must** be unique: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#concept-id

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I do not want to use jQuery and used Simple JavaScript instead of that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, as said my collegues, you cannot have the same id ("IDType") for both your radio buttons.

Here is a solution with javascript only, without any jquery.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Validate() {
    var radios = document.getElementsByName('IDType')

    for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked) {
        alert("Selected Value = " + radios[i].value);
        return true; // checked
    }
    };

    // not checked, show error
    document.getElementById('ValidationError').innerHTML = 'Error!!!';
    return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<div>
<span>
<input type="radio" name="IDType" value="IDtype1"/>
ID Type 1
<input type="radio" name="IDType" value="IDtype2"/>
ID Type 2
</span>
<div id="ValidationError" name="ValidationError">
</div>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return Validate();" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function validateRadioButtons(){ 
    var radio = $('input:radio[name="IDType"]:checked');
    if(radio.length == 0)//no buttons selected
       {
           $('ValidationError').text("you haven't selected any buttons!");
           return;
       }
    $('ValidationError').text(radio.val()+' is selected');
}
```

ps: in order for  this to work, you should consider using unique id's for dom elements. you cannot have the same id ("IDType") for both your radio buttons.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I do not want to use jQuery and used Simple JavaScript instead of that.