# javascript Validation gives alert even when all radio buttons checked

Tags: javascript

i have tried this code to set a validation on a form with 3 radio buttons inputs to give the user alert when NOT all the buttons has checked! .. but when i tried it , it gives me error alert even when all buttons checked .. any idea why ?

this is my form

```
   <form name="form1" action="mark.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post"> 

     <tr>
        <th> Your attendance<font size="4" > </font></th>
        <td>  <input type="radio" name ="v1" value = "4"    onclick="updateTotal();"/></td>
        <td>  <input type="radio" name ="v1" value = "3"    onclick="updateTotal();" /></td>
        <td>  <input type="radio" name ="v1" value = "2"    onclick="updateTotal();" /></td>
        <td>  <input type="radio" name ="v1" value = "1"    onclick="updateTotal();" /></td>    
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <th > Your grades  <font size="4" > </font></th>
        <td>  <input type="radio" name ="v2" value = "4"    onclick="updateTotal();" /></td>
        <td>  <input type="radio" name ="v2" value = "3"    onclick="updateTotal();" /></td>
        <td>  <input type="radio" name ="v2" value = "2"    onclick="updateTotal();" /></td>
        <td>  <input type="radio" name ="v2" value = "1"    onclick="updateTotal();" /></td>    
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <th >Your self-control <font size="4" > </font></th>
        <td>  <input type="radio" name ="v3" value = "4"    onclick="updateTotal();" /></td>
        <td>  <input type="radio" name ="v3" value = "3"    onclick="updateTotal();" /></td>
        <td>  <input type="radio" name ="v3" value = "2"    onclick="updateTotal();" /></td>
        <td>  <input type="radio" name ="v3" value = "1"    onclick="updateTotal();" /></td>    
        </tr>
```

i have tried this javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm(formData){
    if(!this.v1.checked && !this.v2.checked && !this.v3.checked){
        alert('answer all questions please');
        return false;
    }
       return true;
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: please post all of your code

Comment: @Prisoner: Actually, this bit is sufficient...

Comment: Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977084/javascript-radiobutton-group-validation

Answer (score 2):

First problem is you need to pass the form in validateForm():

```
<form name="form1" action="mark.php" onsubmit="return validateForm(this)" method="post"> 
                                                                   ^ pass this
```

Next problem is you are checking `this.v1` when `this` doesn't exist, it should be `formData.v1`.

Final problem is you can't check if a radio button group is checked like that, `formData.v1` is a `nodeList` so you need to loop over it. See my example below using a helper function `groupChecked()`.

```
    function groupChecked(group)
    {
        for(var i=0; i<group.length; i++)
        {
            if(group[i].checked)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

function validateForm(formData){
    if(!(groupChecked(formData.v1) && groupChecked(formData.v2) && groupChecked(formData.v3))){
        alert('answer all questions please');
        return false;
    }
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>Given A, B and C the radio buttons respectively, you want all of the situations **except** the one where all of the buttons are checked. (One of the buttons isn't checked)</s>

```
!(A && B && C)
```

Or in other words:

```
!A || !B || !C
```

Translated to code, this is:

```
if (!(this.v1.checked && this.v2.checked && this.v3.checked)) {
```

After a bit of digging, you can't just check if one of a group of radios is checked like that. You need to loop the nodes individually (this.v1[i].checked) and check those. If you are using a framework like jQuery, it's easier.

Comment: i've changed to this one .. same problem occurs :(

Comment: @JannaSmith: When exactly do you want to alert the message, when one of the three isn't checked, or when none of them are checked?

Comment: when one of the three isn't checked

Answer (score 0):

Is more easy if you use jquery, so add the line

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

And add function:

```
function validate(){
    $("input[name=v1]").each(function(){ 
       if($(this).is(":checked")){
           return false;
        } 
    });

    $("input[name=v2]").each(function(){ 
       if($(this).is(":checked")){
           return false;
        } 
    });

    $("input[name=v3]").each(function(){ 
       if($(this).is(":checked")){
           return false;
        } 
    });

    return true;
}
```

So... you can refactory this code.